# Expected square matrix?

Tags: python, sympy

Kindly help in finding out the error.

```
import sympy as sp
from scipy.linalg import solve
x, y, z,w = sp.symbols('x,y,z,w')
alpha,beta, gamma, delta = sp.symbols('alpha,beta,gamma,delta')
f1 = alpha*y*z - beta*w
f2= gamma*z - delta*x
f3=-alpha*y*z + beta*w + x
f4= -alpha*y*z + beta*w - gamma*z + delta*x
K=solve(f1,f2,f3,f4)
print K
```

The error showing is

```
Expected square matrix
```

Comment: Can you post the entire trace-back?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.linalg.solve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html) does not solve SymPy equations.  Use a SymPy solver.  See, for example, http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html